# Ubuntu 18.04 can't login after software update

Tags: login, update-manager, lock-screen

I have a small NUC which acts as my network gateway. I normally have a terminal session running on a console and run whatever software updates are offered as and when. Frequently (not every time but frequently enough to be tiresome) when the update has completed the console shows a lock screen with arrows scrolling from the bottom. As far as I can tell it is inviting me to swipe upwards - except this isn't a touch screen and I can't swipe up with keyboard or mouse. Nor can I find a key or key-combination which brings back the login prompt.

[image: Like so:]

When this occurs I can either pull the power cord and do a cold reboot, or ssh onto the NUC from another machine and do a more graceful restart.

When the attached screen is visible, if I move the mouse to the top left corner I can open an applications dropdown and start an application - but although the status line shows the application running I can't view it - it's opened on a desktop which I cannot get to.

Can anyone advise me of a better way through this - or what kind of missing or corrupted file might be responsible for it happening?

cheers
T

Comment: Why the cutting power (unclean shutdown)?  Has keyboard stopped responding, thus you cannot shutdown/reboot using Sysrq keys?  Sorry I can't help with your real issue.

Comment: I don't know if the keyboard is responding or not because I can't see an active window. I'd never heard of Sysrq keys, so thank you, I'll see if that helps. It's an old microsoft keyboard, so the first exercise is to discover how to trigger it.